# check if json parent value is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

What method can I use to find out if json parent value are empty or not?

Basically I have a url that looks like this

```
catalogue/items.json?category=1&item=scarf
```

and there are more than 10 categories

I want to search all the categories until it finds out that json actually returns a valid index of price, etc.. (Even if item does not exist in the category it will still print out how many items are in the category in the json)

Example:

If scarf exists in category 2

```
{"total":100,"items":["name":"Scarf", "current":{"price":"122.5"}]}
```

If scarf does not exist in category 2

```
{"total":100,"items":[]}
```

Comment: It's not clear what particular JSON object you're searching, what the format looks like, how close a match you need (the case doesn't match), or what the result is supposed to look like (what you've shown is invalid JSON).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you have incorrect JSON string but I use correct version.

```
import json

#-----

json_str = '''{"total":100,"items":{"name":"Scarf", "current":{"price":"122.5"}}}'''

data = json.loads(json_str)

if 'name' in data['items'] and data['items']['name'].lower() == 'scarf':
    print 'There is Scarf'
else:
    print 'There is NO Scarf'        

#-----

json_str = '''{"total":100,"items":{}}'''

data = json.loads(json_str)

if 'name' in data['items'] and data['items']['name'].lower() == 'scarf':
    print 'There is Scarf'
else:
    print 'There is NO Scarf'
```

Result:

```
There is Scarf
There is NO Scarf
```

---

**EDIT:** as [karthikr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1628832/karthikr) suggested you can use

```
if data.get('items', {}).get('name', '').lower() == 'scarf':
    print 'There is Scarf'
else:
    print 'There is NO Scarf'
```

Comment: if 'name' in data['items']
That is what I needed thanks.

Edit : Clicked save too early

Comment: +1 Alternatively, You could just do `data.get('items', {}).get('name', '').lower() == 'scarf'`